# how to filter a sql condition in c#

Tags: c#

i have the following table is sql

> **Id | transaction**
>
> 15 |4785-t48er8-565
>
> 24 |4587-dsfs-89554
>
> 784|sdf487-89d5-5sd

in my program i pass in a **transaction**  in which i first need to check if the transaction **exists** in the database as follows

```
     var entry = (await _Repository.AsQueryableAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.transaction == command.transaction);
     if (entry !=null)
    {
    // do something
    }
```

so the above works.
My question is the transaction that exists how do i check if that transaction is equal to the `id` i pass in

for example if i pass the following response from my api as

```
"transaction": "4785-t48er8-565",
"id":569
```

it will then check with the above code that the transaction exists. Now as you can see in the table the transaction **4785-t48er8-565** has an id of **15**
but in my response i passed in **569**

how do i check if the transaction matches the id. I need to check first if it exists and then match it to the id

Comment: FirstOrDefault allows to have multiple conditions with logical operators AND and OR. Not just a single condition

Comment: yes it has multiple conditions

Comment: _FirstOrDefault(x => x.transaction == command.transaction && x.id == command.id) ;_

Comment: @Steve the transaction might exist for a different id and this will think that the transaction doesnt exists in the table. i cant use it in the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add it to the same condition you already have, like:

```
    var entry = (await _Repository.AsQueryableAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.transaction == command.transaction);

    if (entry !=null)
    {
      if (entry.id != command.id)
      {
         // then it already exists for a different id
      }
      else
      {
         //then entry is the one that matches transaction and id
      }
    }
```

Then `entry` will be null if the condition for both properties is not met.

Comment: no i need to check first if the transaction exists in the entire table,because if the transaction doesnt exists then i do some stuff,but if the transaction exists then i want to match it on the id.

Comment: the transaction  might exist for a different id and this will think that the transaction doesnt exists in the table

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test first for the Transaction and then separately on the Id, try:

```
        var entry = (await _Repository.AsQueryableAsync()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.transaction == command.transaction);
        if (entry == null)
        {
            // do no transaction stuff
        }
        else if (entry.Id == command.Id)
        {
            // do matching stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do transaction found but Id doesn't match stuff
        }
```

Comment: this will result in a NullReferenceException in the `else if`.

Comment: @devcrp first test should have been "entry==null" as per the comment.  I've corrected now.  I see my answer overlapped with yours.  That wasn't intentional.